# Junits FLux Test Cases fix for 100%

Tags: java, spring

class YourClassTest {

```
@Mock
private EventObjectResponse eventObjectResponse;

@Mock
private ResponseEventEntity responseEventEntity;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}

@Test
void testMappedResponse() {
    when(eventObjectResponse.getFluxResponseEventEntity()).thenReturn(Flux.just(responseEventEntity));
    when(eventObjectResponse.getPagingToken()).thenReturn("token");

    CommandResponse commandResponse = YourClass.mappedResponse(eventObjectResponse);

    assertEquals("token", commandResponse.getPagingToken());
    verify(eventObjectResponse, times(1)).getFluxResponseEventEntity();
    verify(eventObjectResponse, times(1)).getPagingToken();
}

@Test
void testMappingMetaData() throws Exception {
    when(responseEventEntity.getEventMetadata()).thenReturn("v1:{\"sourceAppId\":\"source\",\"clientAppId\":\"client\",\"requestedByAgent\":\"agent\",\"properties\":{}}");

    Tuple2<ResponseEventEntity, CommandMetadata> result = YourClass.mappingMetaData(responseEventEntity);

    assertEquals(responseEventEntity, result.getT1());
    assertEquals("source", result.getT2().getSourceAppId());
    assertEquals("client", result.getT2().getClientAppId());
    assertEquals("agent", result.getT2().getRequestedByAgent());
    verify(responseEventEntity, times(1)).getEventMetadata();
}
```

}

Updated answer this looks good  and can be used to write junits test case
If any help needed can take an other look at it

Comment: Did you intend to post this as answer to a question?